# Vertical alignment of cells in UITableView instead of top-down alignment

Tags: iphone, uitableview, vertical-alignment

I am newbie to objective-c.So apologies in advance if this question sounds simple.As we all know that in a table view,when ever we specify the number of rows/sections as let's say 8.
Then the alignment of cells obviously would be from top to bottom,i.e. horizontal alignment.

Now when ever the number of cells increases,we need to scroll the table view to get control or view the remaining cells(rows/sections).Say if the number of cells are 8,we can view 5 cells and upon scrolling the remaining 3.

So what I want is the side by side alignment of cells,i.e. vertical alignment say if I have 8 cells,then 2 cells in each column with 4 rows.So that the user need not scroll to view the remaining cells.

Can any one please suggest me a hint or sample code

Comment: If there is no need for scroll, then instead of implementing it as tableview you could use Buttons/textfields/labels and customize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this effect:

- You can do the suggested **custom cell** with two "cell" views
- You could put **two tables next to each other** and synchronize their scrolling by reacting on the scrollViewDidScroll events and adjusting the content offsets accordingly
- Or you can use one of the **Grid views** flying around in the Open Source, e.g. http://blog.alanquatermain.me/2010/04/17/aqgridview-lives/

Comment: Thanks for the answer,will implement and get back to you

Comment: But one doubt,as you suggested to take two table views,that's fine but  how do I differentiate number of sections in the return count of the number of rows in section and number of section in uitableview.

Comment: All calls to tableView functions also have the table as an argument - you can check it to see which table the call is for, provided you saved the table reference in your class, eg if(tableView == leftTableView)

Comment: Oh k Mr.Eye,will try to implement and get back to you

Comment: Yeah the 2 table views concept is working,but with small issues,no problem.I can fix them.Doesn't my question deserve an up vote :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but probably not in the way that you are hoping to.

Using your example, you would create a custom cell that *looks* like two separate cells. Just be sure to load the appropriate data in your cell for row method.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Sosborn for the answer,but I am unable to get you completely.How can we make a cell look/appear as two.Can you give me a sample code for loading appr. data in cell for row at index path method,thanks